# Calling function when importing file

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I'm using Python about a week so this might be a very stupid question.
Just hit a very strange situation.
I have a file EventActions.py:

```
from subprocess import call

def ResetDevice():
    print("Reseting device")
    call(["sudo", "reboot"])
    print("Wait for it...")
```

The problem I occured is that the function ResetDevice is actually called when I'm importing this file via

```
import EventActions
```

I'm starting my program via SSH connection to Raspberry Pi. After this the device is of course rebooting.

Comment: Are those snippets the complete files?

Comment: Can you post the complete EventActions.py?

Comment: I'm almost sure that the above code is just a snippet, there must be something in `EventActions.py` that "does" something.

Comment: you must be calling the function somewhere in `EventActions `

Comment: Put something illegal at the beginning of `ResetDevice()` that will case an exception, then when the function is called you'll get a traceback showing how it got called.